# UIButton on UIView behind two other UIViews reacts to touches on the views above

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview, storyboard, layer

I'm just starting out learning about iOS GUI after playing around with backend stuff and Objective-C in general the last few weeks. I've stumbled upon a tricky situation that I've managed to solve but I want to know if there is a better way to solve it.

Here's how I've layered my UIViews:

```
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:_topView.layer above:self.view.layer];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:_bottomView.layer above:self.view.layer];
```

So I have the "base" view and a single ViewController. In this view I have two subviews: topView and bottomView. I have been able to manipulate the origin of these views just like I want but even when they are in front of my UIButton it reacts to touch.

I solved this by checking the y axis of the origin of one of the subviews (it doesn't matter which one) to make sure that the button is revealed and thus activate it (or enable user interaction, rather).

```
if (_topView.frame.origin.y == 0) {
    self.refreshButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
} else {
    self.refreshButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

I personally dislike this solution and would like to know what a better way to solve this is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction so that I get this layer business going without ugly hacks here and there?

I am using storyboards with Xcode 5.0.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't feel like that's a hack, it's a perfectly good way to accomplish what you're trying to do. As far as feeling long and verbose, your other alternative is going to be hit-testing the views and handling an NSSet of touches, which will seem like way more work than what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting sublayers doesn't affect touch forwarding at all. A view's subview (in your case a button) can only be "covered" by adding a subview over it. If you don't have a special reason to use `CALayer`s then just add subviews instead, then it'll process the touches the right way. Like this:

```
[self.view insertSubview:_topView aboveSubview:self.refreshButton];
[self.view insertSubview:_bottomView aboveSubview:self.refreshButton];
```

Comment: You'll still need to selectively enable and disable user interaction with subviews. I was assuming you NEEDED sublayer's for some reason, but it would be far more common to stack views in a hierarchy. Either way, userInteractionEnabled is the way to go.

Comment: The problem was that the button did react to touches, which won't happen with subviews since they have the `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES` by default. Difference between subviews and sublayers is exactly user interaction handling - layers don't handle it, subviews do.

Comment: I'll give this a go when I go home from work. Thanks!